# How to create an array of functions inside a loop in c

Tags: c

Here is what I'm doing right now:

```
double fb0(const double *x, const double *par){ // B0'
    return -par[0]+(1-Cxr(0,2)*par[1])*x[0]+Cxr(0,2)*par[1]*x[0]; 
}
double fb1(const double *x, const double *par){ // B1'
    return -par[0]+(1-Cxr(1,2)*par[1])*x[1]+Cxr(1,2)*par[1]*x[1];
}
double fb2(const double *x, const double *par){ // B2'
    return -par[0]+(1-Cxr(2,2)*par[1])*x[2]+Cxr(3,2)*par[1]*x[3];
}
double fb3(const double *x, const double *par){ // B3'
    return -par[0]+(1-Cxr(3,2)*par[1])*x[3]+Cxr(4,2)*par[1]*x[4];
}
double fb4(const double *x, const double *par){ // B4'
    return -par[0]+(1-Cxr(4,2)*par[1])*x[4]+Cxr(5,2)*par[1]*x[5];
}
...
```

And it goes until fb20. I then call each function inside my `void main(){}`. What I would like to do is to have something like this before my `void main(){}`:

```
for(int i=0;i<20;i++){
   double fb[i](const double *x, const double *par){return -par[0]+(1-Cxr(i,2)*par[1])*x[i]+Cxr(i+1,2)*par[1]*x[i+1];}
}
```

Is this possible? This way I am able to solve a system of equations with any i.

Comment: Unrelated: `void main(){}` should be `int main(){}`.

Comment: Rolled back changes because they invalidated a correct answer. When you find you've oversimplified or otherwise asked the wrong question after the question has been answered, wait for the question cooldown to expire and ask a new question.

Comment: Recommendation: Take the [tour] that was offered when you signed up with Stack Overflow and then read [ask] and at least the [Asking Questions portion](https://stackoverflow.com/help/asking) of the help pages to get a better feel for how to use the site.

Answer (score 5):

simply add one more parameter

```
double fb(const double *x, const double *par, size_t num)
{
    return -par[0]+(1-Cxr(num,2)*par[1])*x[num]+Cxr(num + 1,2)*par[1]*x[num + 1]; 
}
```

... and you will not need 20 functions

Comment: I edited my question to clarify how I use the function inside ```void main```. So, if I do what you said I will still have one function address and I will not be able to wrap it several times with different "num" values. Do you agree?

Comment: @Jeremias you created X-Y problem